# Hover one div change the other?

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I'm wondering if someone could help me with a Jquery css question.

```
<div class='post'>
    <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
</div>
```

What I'm wondering is how to tack an image next to the title while hovering over the post div.
Then on mouse out the image will not be displayed.

I'm using php while loop to display ten post divs per page.

Comment: Add the image, but set its display to none in the CSS.
Then, add a jQuery function for mouseover of that title block, and set display to block if true. When mouse exits, set display back to hidden.

Comment: @dynamic The more elegant way is to set a CSS class and let CSS do the work.

Comment: It doesn't work on older browsers. I suggested the more stable way but if your site is tailored to more tech-savvy users the CSS way would definitely be better.

Comment: @dynamic That is not true. In my answer, I have an example using JS to modify the CSS class on hover. It's not 100% CSS but it's still more elegant than having your script update the style property directly.

Comment: Is there even a browser since IE 5 that doesn't support `.post:hover h1`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it didn't work properly until IE 7. IE5.5 and IE6 are problematic (only works on `<a>`) http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover

Comment: @JuanMendes Ah I see. I stopped writing code compatible with IE 6 a while ago so I've forgotten what works in it and doesn't, but I was pretty sure `:hover` worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
$('.post').bind({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        $(this).append('<img />');
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        $('img', this).remove();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrCwV/)

Comment: @nathancahill All the answers work! Let the OP chose the one he thought best answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear exactly what you want (where do you want the image to go?), but you can do something like this easily with just CSS:

```
.post h1 {
    padding-left: 25px;   
}

.post:hover h1 {
    background: url(http://www.dummyimage.com/20x20/000000/000) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

​
[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/rBYMZ/)

This will work in IE 7 and newer browsers, provided that you use a [strict doctype](http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762) (for IE 7 support). It still will not work in IE 6.

Answer (score 2):

Look ma, no JavaScript http://jsfiddle.net/zNbHE/

```
<div class='post'>
    <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
    <img width="50" height="50">
</div>​


div:hover img {
    visibility: visible;
}   
div img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
​
```

If you need to support really old browsers (that don't suport `:hover` on anything but links) You can fake it with jQuery. With the added bonus that the image will be there the whole time if JS is disabled.

```
$(".post").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);

div.hover img {
    visibility: visible;
}   
div img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```